gitlab integration url don't change
I had Youtrack issue tracker integrated with my gitlab and everything worked OK - I created commit with issue name and gitlab showed it as a link to Youtrack issue page.
Recently we had to migrate Youtrack from cloud to self-hosted server, so Youtrack URL has changed. I updated integration settings in gitlab, links in new commits works OK, but links in old commits(before URL changed) still point to the old Youtrack's URL.
Project integration settings page:
Issue link pointed to the old URL:
Is there any way to update old issue links?
